# A term for this type of language

Tags: euphemisms

For example, you're in a room with three people. You're talking to one person and the other is getting kind of stupid or is doing something that you find dumb.

To insult them without them catching on to what you actually mean, you come up with a statement that you say to the person that you're talking to, and it sounds like you're talking about something else, like your dog, but you're really insulting the person.

Comment: Btw, what is *this* type of language called?

Comment: The words Deride and Mock comes to mind

Comment: A related term (but not what you are looking for) is 'dogwhistle', which means using words in such a way that they sound normal to most people, but there's an underlying connection that a small group of people will understand for themselves. Lots of political speech supposedly has lots of '[dogwhistles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog-whistle_politics)'.

Answer (score 10):

You could say that is a [veiled insult](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/veiled).

Answer (score 2):

It's called ***charientism***

> derived from a Greek word meaning a figure of speech wherein a taunting expression is softened by a jest, an insult veiled in grace (wiki)
>
> **Edit**: I just found another earlier reference to this form of Rhetoric: it is also referred to as [***charientismus***](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.03.0082%3Apart%3DTropes%3Asubpart%3DCharientismus).

Also commonly referred to as ***backhanded complement***

Another term for this type of [***backhanded compliment***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/backhanded?s=t) is
***asteism***

> polite and ingenious irony (freedictionary.com)

Comment: Can you add that to one answer and delete the other? And link to the terms using [ word ] ( URL ) - but who says it is supposed to be softened?

Answer (score 2):

I like "innuendo."

[Webster's Definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/innuendo?show=0&t=1377967938)

[Related Words](http://thesaurus.com/browse/innuendo)

Answer (score -2):

It is not a single term for it, but if you are paraphrasing an insult you might call it "hidden slander".

Comment: Slander is a specific type of insult with possible legal ramifications _The action or crime of making a false spoken statement damaging to a person's reputation._

Comment: Still, I have seen "hidden slander" used for this. At least, if the person targeted gets the insult, they might sue for slander afterwards.

Comment: How? If I say Monkey see, Monkey do to my friend, how can the person I refer to sue for slander?

Comment: I am not saying they would win the lawsuit.

Comment: Maybe *slander* is used differently in different countries, and does not always refer to a legally actionable insult?

Comment: Slander is not necessarily an insult. It is negative but if I say "Dr. X killed a man" and he didn't or I cannot prove it, he can sue me for slander where applicable but I could say it as a fact and not like I would say "Dr. X is a monkey's arse"

Comment: Slander is a *false* statement. It does not imply an attempt to insult.